# Android - java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension: type=0x12

Tags: android, xml, layout, android-linearlayout

I'm trying to make a UI for my android application, but it crashes and error is

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.test/com.example.test.MainActivity}: 
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert to dimension:
>   type=0x12"

Here's my XML code

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ff000000"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/symbolName"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" >
    </EditText>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/RadioButton01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/RadioButton02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/RadioButton03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="RadioButton" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/condition" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="@+id/RadioButton03">

        <EditText 
            android:inputType="number"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Add Alert"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

What I'm doing wrong? Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've provided invalid resource at this line:

```
android:layout_marginTop="@+id/RadioButton03"
```

dimentions should be used for margin, e.g.

```
android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_top"
```

Answer (score 1):

Error in this Line

```
android:layout_marginTop="@+id/RadioButton03"
```

Total code is as below:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/symbolName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
    android:textColor="#ffffffff" >
</EditText>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radioButton1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButton01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButton02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/RadioButton03"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/condition"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</LinearLayout>

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Add Alert" />
```